# Can we derive that the wavefunction changes as $\Psi'(\vec{r},t)=e^{i(q/\hslash c)\Lambda(\vec{r},t)}\Psi(\vec{r},t)$ under a gauge transformation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, schroedinger-equation, gauge-invariance

The relevant time-dependent Schrodinger equation, for a spinless charged particle in an EM field, reads
$$
i\hslash\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}=\left[\frac{1}{2 m}\left(\vec{p}-\frac{q}{c}\vec{A}\right)^{2}+q\phi\right]\Psi
$$
where $\vec{p}=-i\hslash\nabla$. The wavefunctions, $\Psi$ and $\Psi^\prime$, due to a pair of potentials $(\phi,\vec{A})$ and $(\phi',\vec{A}')$ respectively, that are related to each other by a gauge transformation is related as
$$
\Psi'(\vec{r},t)=e^{i(q/\hslash c)\Lambda(\vec{r},t)}\Psi(\vec{r},t).\tag{1}
$$
where $\Lambda$ is the gauge function. This **can be verified** by direct substitution. But **can we derive** this result? QM textbooks always verify this result knowing it beforehand. But is there a way to derive it?

Comment: Maybe begin with Ψ'=Ψ+δψ (correction)... substitute this in Schrodinger equation , manipulate the kinetic term in RHS by adding and subtracting p²/2m and see how δψ is related to Ψ

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/562654/2451

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is derive it backwards. Start with a pure global phase, convert it to local phase, see how to modify that so that it would fit the requirements of gauge symmetry. i.e. start with $$e^{i\varepsilon\Lambda(\vec r,t)}$$ and derive what const $\varepsilon$ will fit what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well a gauge transformation can't have any physical consequences so the wavefunction must transform with an overall phase, which means that
$$\psi\to e^{im(x)}\psi.$$ Plug this into the SE equation together with the transformation for $A$ and requiring all the new terms to vanish gives you the desired result.